# Windows remote desktop multi-screen independiently minimize

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

Often, I work on a remote desktop session, from a Windows computer to another Windows.

I want to know if I can connect using my two screens, but, with independent minimize controls.

This are resolved on remote desktop for mac (microsoft official client), who allows to go to local desktop on each screen independent. But on Windows, if I check the option for use all monitors, they go to full screen, and if I minimize, they go to local desktop on all screens.

Are this possible to do on windows?

Comment: Are these always the same two computers (client & server)? Are they both on Windows 10? Can you install third-party software on the server?

Comment: Yes, We're talking about same computers. One with Windows 11 to another with Windows 10. No third-party remote access software, only MS Terminal Services.